# SQLAlchemy create trigger after its tables exist

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a trigger which deletes a row from table B when table A is updated.

I am using the following code to create the trigger via `DDL`:

```
event.listen(                                                               
        TableA.__table__,                                              
        'after_create',                                                     
        my_trig_ddl.execute_if(dialect='mysql')                          
)
```

But, error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1146 (42S02): Table 'sqlalchemy_example.TableB' doesn't exist
```

How can I solve this other than guessing which table is created last? This seems like a bad solution as upgrades or code re-factoring may change the order in which tables are created.

Comment: Currently have the same problem creating a view. Someone have found a solution to this?